# Wordpress multisite disable all default widgets on site creation

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm unable to find how to disable the default widgets on site creation. By this I mean when I create a site within a Wordpress multisite network, it does not create the sidebar widgets such as "meta" automatically.

I see plugins that haven't been updated in two plus years that may help me with this, but I don't want to download anything that old.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The default widgets are created by a call to `update_option()` in `wp_install_defaults()` in `wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php`.

After `wp_install_defaults()` has been called by `wpmu_create_blog()` in `wp-includes/ms-functions.php`, the action `wpmu_new_blog` is fired.

You can, therefore, hook into `wpmu_new_blog` and remove the default widgets by calling `update_option()` again, this time with an empty array for `sidebar-1`.

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', function($blog_id){
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);
    update_option('sidebars_widgets',
        ['wp_inactive_widgets' => [], 'sidebar-1' => [], 'sidebar-2' => [],
         'sidebar-3' => [], 'array_version' => 3]);
    restore_current_blog();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe unregister_widget is what you are looking for.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5552/how-to-hide-or-remove-unwanted-widgets-on-multisite-installation

Comment: I actually don't want to get rid of the widget altogether... I just don't want the widget to appear in the sidebar by default when a site is created. Any thoughts?